# How to make google show page preview

Tags: google-search

The website shows in google search, but it doesnt show page preview. Instead it shows the company logo (an image at the top of the homepage) in the place for the preview.

What can cause google to show the logo, instead of the full page preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several days the problem resolved itself. I guess google recrawled the site and corrected the preview. Or it might have been a problem with the system of offering links by ip activity, as i was visiting the site frequently, and didnt test the preview on a different machine...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried researching the problem? Maybe this will help.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1062498

Comment: I did.  Snippet, robots, useragent.. all are ok... no rich content too.